# setState not applying initial state when trying to initialize it to an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have a To-Do List app that makes an API call to get a list of all stored tasks that I want to display upon loading the screen, however I can't seem to call setState after the API call without it getting stuck on a promise or setTasks just printing null after setTasks(newTasks) within the getTasks function. I've tested this by calling getTasks in another function (ex addTasks, that runs fine, and just logging to console after the function call). Additionally, my current scheme sometimes loads with an uncaught promise error from axios that I can't seem to trace. Sorry I'm new to React/frontend in general so I may be missing the obvious.

```
function ToDoList() {
    const [tasks, setTasks]  = useState([])

    const getTasks = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(endpoint + "/api/task")
        console.log(response)

        if (response.data)
        {
            const data = response.data
            var newTasks = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                const task = {
                    id: data[i].id,
                    text: data[i].task,
                    status: data[i].status,
                }
                newTasks = [task, ...newTasks];
            }
            return newTasks;
        }
        else 
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getTasks().then((newTasks) => {
            setTasks([newTasks,... tasks]);
        });
    }, []);
```

So far I've tried recreating this by passing in props in the file that loads this component, but I was having issues with passing them in. I also have tried calling setTasks within getTasks, however it never seems to apply? I can verify the array is created correctly, however the call to setTasks at the end of getTasks seems to never change anything.

Comment: does this `console.log(response)` return what you expect?

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is. If you're getting any error messages, please [edit] your question to include them **in full**. Also, where / how are you using the `tasks` state? How are you verifying that `setTasks` is _"not applying"_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems I can see with this approach...

1. If `<StrictMode>` is enabled, this will result in duplicate data in `tasks` because effect hooks execute multiple times.
2. `getTasks()` can possibly resolve with `null` which isn't spreadable
3. If the request succeeds, `response.data` is **always** set. There is no need to check `if (response.data)`

To solve the first two, you should just set the data rather than try and spread it.

There's also no need for your `for` loop when you can simply use [Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

```js
// This could be in its own module, not tied to your component
const getTasks = async () =>
  (await axios.get("/api/task", { baseURL: endpoint })).data
    .reverse()
    .map(({ id, task, status }) => ({
      id,
      text: task,
      status,
    }));
```

and in your component call `getTasks()` and pass the result to `setTasks()`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getTasks().then(setTasks).catch(console.warn);
}, []);
```

Comment: `useEffect` running twice will not set duplicate data in `newTasks` because its value is still equal to `[]` the second time `useEffect` is exectued

Comment: yes I would like

Comment: shoul I wait or go to sleep ? please tell me, and sorry

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-scooby-rxdh0o?file=/src/App.js

Comment: nice trick I like it, please delete the first remark it is not correct